# ¿Como puedo colocar color a una columna segunda la condicion si es APROBADA O RECHAZADA?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, dom

```
introducir el código aquí

    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

.APROBADO{
    background-color: red;         
}

.RECHAZADO{
    background-color: red;          
}
</style>

function cargaPagina(pagina)
{
    var desde = pagina * itemsPorPagina;
    $.ajax({
        data:{"param1":"dame","limit":itemsPorPagina,"offset":desde},
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"Conexion_Tabla_Cotizacion.php"
    }).done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){

        var lista = data.lista;

        $("#miTabla").html("");

        var colorsStyle = [
        "APROVADO", "RECHAZADO"        
        ]


        $.each(lista, function(ind, elem){

//Obtengo la fecha del elemento actual en la iteración
var fecha_str = elem.estado_orden_compra_venta.toString();
//Obtengo el número del mes, y le resto 1 para poder asociarlo al arreglo ya que este comienza en el índice 0 y el primer mes es el 
var classs = colorsStyle[fecha_str];


$("<tr>"+

    '<td>'+elem.razon_social_empresa+'</td>'+
    '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_solicitud_pedido+'</a></td>'+

             //cotizacion//


             '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Cotizacion.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_solicitud_cotizacion+'</a></td>'+
             '<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">' +
             '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Modificar</button> '+

             //Orden de compra o venta//P

             '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Orden_Compra_Venta.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_orden_compra_venta+'</a></td>'+

             '<td>'+elem.estado_orden_compra_venta+'</td>'+
             '<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">' +
             '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir1('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Ingresar</button> '+

            //Factura//
            '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Factura.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_factura+'</a></td>'+
            '<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir3('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Ingresar</button> '+'</td>'+ 

            // Estado Cotizacion

            '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Estado_Cotizacion.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_estado_cotizacion+'</a></td>'+
            '<td>'+elem.fecha_pago_estado+'</td>'+
            '<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir4('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Ingresar</button> '+'</td>'+ 

            '</tr>').appendTo($("#miTabla"));

    });     


    }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,textError){
        alert("Error al realizar la peticion dame".textError);

      });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero lo aplicas para cada columna o para todas las columnas? y cual seria la condicion?

Comment: Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta y coloca más información.

Comment: aja pero cual es la columna? rechazado no es una condicion.. una condicion seria si el valor de la variable es nula deberia colocar algo, si tiene un numero mayo a algo, da esto otro y asi... si tu no compartes y explicas lo que quieres con lo que tienes.. nadie te puede ayudar.. nosotros no estamos en tu mente..

Comment: Cual campo de tu tabla es la que vas a comprobar que tenga el valor "rechazado", es archivo_estado_cotizacion por casualidad???

Comment: Que tiene que tener el mes para que le pongas un color y que color vas a ponerle, ah y es la fila completa la que vas a cambiar o solo esa celda?

Comment: Si pero que criterio es el ke vas a usar para comparar

Comment: Eso quiere decir que vas a tener 12 colores??

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas  mas abajo comente lo que me habias dicho, no se si logras entenderme saludos –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Creo los estilos para cada mes, los colores son los que tu quieras.
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    .enero{
      background-color: gray;         
    }
    .febrero{
      background-color: red;          
    }
    .marzo{
      background-color: white;        
    }
    .abril{
      background-color: green;        
    }
    .mayo{
      background-color: yellow;       
    }
    .junio{
      background-color: blue;         
    }
    .julio{
      background-color: violet;       
    }
    .agosto{
      background-color: pink;         
    }
    .septiembre{
      background-color: orange;       
    }
    .octubre{
      background-color: brown;        
    }
    .noviembre{
      background-color: aqua;         
    }
    .diciembre{
      background-color: lime;         
    }
</style>

//Dentro del done de tu ajax, reemplazalo por lo siguiente

var lista = data.lista;

$("#miTabla").html("");

//Establezo un arreglo con los nombres de las clases correspondientes a los meses
var colorsStyle = [
    "enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio",
    "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"        
]

$.each(lista, function(ind, elem){
    //Obtengo la fecha del elemento actual en la iteración
    var fecha_str = elem.fecha_pago_estado.toString();
    //Obtengo el número del mes, y le resto 1 para poder asociarlo al arreglo ya que este comienza en el índice 0 y el primer mes es el 1
    var mes = parseInt(fecha_str.split('-')[1])-1;
    //Establezco el nombre de la clase basado en el mes
    var class = colorsStyle[mes];
    //Asigno la clase a la fila actual antes de crearla
    $("<tr class=\""+class+"\">"+

        '<td>'+elem.razon_social_empresa+'</td>'+
        '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_solicitud_pedido+'</a></td>'+

 //cotizacion//


 '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Cotizacion.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_solicitud_cotizacion+'</a></td>'+
 '<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">' +
 '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Modificar</button> '+

 //Orden de compra o venta//P

 '<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Orden_Compra_Venta.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_orden_compra_venta+'</a></td>'+

 '<td  bgcolor="bbbbbb">'+elem.total_orden_compra+'</td>'+
 '<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">' +
 '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir1('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Ingresar</button> '+

//Factura//
'<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Factura.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_factura+'</a></td>'+
'<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">' +
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir2('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Ingresar</button> '+'</td>'+ 

// Estado Cotizacion

'<td><a target="_blank" href="Mostrar_PDF_Estado_Cotizacion.php?id='+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+elem.archivo_estado_cotizacion+'</a></td>'+
'<td>'+elem.fecha_pago_estado+'</td>'+
'<td idpersona ="'+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+'">'+
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrir3('+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+')">Ingresar</button> '+'</td>'+ 

'</tr>').appendTo($("#miTabla"));

});
```

Comment: Por lo visto te funciono. Saludos!!!

Comment: Intenta poner console.log(mes) despues de la linea **var mes = parseInt(fecha_str.split('-')[1])-1;** y comprueba que vaya mostrando el numero correcto de los meses renderizados en cada fila

Comment: A ver en donde es que te trabastes para ayudarte

Comment: el sistema que estoy trabajando sufrió una pequeña modificación, antes era por la fecha que se pusiera de un color x, pero ahora es por el estado, lo cual utilice parte de tu codigo estableciendo dos colores uno es para aprobado y otro para rechazado, pero no me funciona

Comment: Que quieres cambiar de color la celda esa en especifico o la fila completa y cual es el nombre de la propiedad asignada al estado que quieres condicionar porque no la encontre en tu código

Comment: ahora agregue el nuevo código y la codicion esta en esta variable estado_orden_compra_venta, porque ahi se encuentra si esta aprobada o rechazada. saludos

Answer (score 2):

Cuando estes creando tu table los `<td></td>` simplemente haz una verificación de cuando es rechazada por ejemplo

```
if(elem.archivo_estado_cotizacion === 1){
     <td class='columnaRoja'></td>
}else{
      <td></td>
}
```

y despues creas una clase en tu css llamada columnaRoja

```
.columnaRoja{
color : #FFF: 
background-color : red
}
```